# Issue with round with Data.Fixed

Tags: haskell

I have defined the following type in myfile.hs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import Data.Typeable
import Data.Fixed

data E18 = E18 deriving (Typeable)
instance HasResolution E18 where resolution _ = 10^18
type MyDouble = Fixed E18

--myRound :: MyDouble > MyDouble 
--myRound x  = round x
```

and whereas the round function works well in ghci :

```
Prelude Data.Fixed> :load myfile.hs
Prelude Data.Fixed> round (3.1::MyDouble)
3
Prelude Data.Fixed>
```

if I append the following code to the file :

```
myRound :: MyDouble -> MyDouble 
myRound x  = round x
```

I get the following compilation error :

```
Prelude Data.Fixed> :load myfile.hs
No instance for (Integral MyDouble)
  arising from a use of round
```

Could someone please tell me how to call round inside a function ?

PS: As you may guess, I'm beginner in Haskell

Comment: Notice `round` might not round the way you want `round` to round.  To round how you want to round then consider rounding with `floor` or `ceiling` instead of `round`, which means round to then nearest even.  Round.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Awesome use of the word round. Awesome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`round` takes one `RealFrac` and produces a `Integral`:

```
round :: (Integral b, RealFrac a) => a -> b
```

Your `myRound` should have about the same type as `round`: take one `MyDouble` and produce an `Int`. So instead of `MyDouble -> Int -> MyDouble`, it should be `MyDouble -> Int`, since (I guess) what you need in the end is an `Int`.

Also note instead of writing

```
myRound x = round x
```

you can just say

```
myRound = round
```

If you want `myRound` produce you a `MyDouble`, then

```
myRound :: MyDouble -> MyDouble 
myRound  = fromIntegral . round
```

should work.

Comment: You are welcome:) use `:t` in GHCi can save you quite some time at times.